# Thickness of OpenGL 2D Textures

Tags: java, opengl, textures, rendering, lwjgl

What is the easiest way to give 2D texture in OpenGL (lwjgl) some kind of "Thickness". Of course i could get the border of the texture somehow and add Quads, orriented by the normal of the quad that the texture is drawn on, in the color of the adjacent texture pixel. But there has to be an easier way to do it.
Minecraft is using lwigl as well and there are the (new) 3D Items, that spin down on the ground and don't cause as much of a performance issue, as is if they were drawn of dozends of polygons. As well, when you hold an item in your hand, there is that kind of "stretched" Texture in depth, which also works with high resolution textures.
Does anyone know how that is done?

Comment: The only way a texture can have apparent thickness I know of is bump mapping (and even that is only apparent thickness, it breaks down when viewed at extreme angles). To create real thickness it must be some geometry generation effect.

Comment: Yep, geometry shader could be used here pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D texture is always infinitely thin. If you want actual thickness (when you look edge onto it) you need geometry. In Minecraft things look blocky, because they've been modeled that way.

If you look at some angle and ignore the edges you can use parallax mapping to "fake" some depth in the texture. Or you can use a depth map and use a combination of tesselation shaders and vertex shaders to implement a displacement map, that generates geometry from the texture.